# Need help on implementing Linked Lists into a TableView javaFX and saving them onto a File

Tags: java, xml, javafx, save

I have an assignment to do that involves saving and writing to a file (doesn't have to be a .XML file but preferably I would like to have it as a .XML file) and most importantly we cannot use **any existing Java collections or data structures classes (e.g. ArrayList, LinkedList, or any other class that implements the Collection interface or any of its children)** . So I tried implementing a doubly linked list into the project but I do not understand the concept of it and I do not know if I had it correctly implemented as I was looking up the forum and other guides for help. I would also need help or advice on saving the linked list into a file. I have tried using the JAXB maven plugin by marshaling and unmarshaling the list but I need to have a working linked list first in order to have that. Unless using the XStream plugin would be a better use? Lastly is to use the filewriter but thats where my knowledge ends anyways. Keeping in mind that I want a tableview to display the lists i.e. such as the user enters the required text and the text to be put up on a tableview (which I have done already) but also that the text can be saved into the list and later read from the .XML file.

This is my show FXML file

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>

<Pane fx:id="showPane" fx:controller="Controllers.showController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <TableView fx:id="showTableView" layoutX="50.0" prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="550.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="setShowName" prefWidth="85.0" text="Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setShowMinutes" prefWidth="59.0" text="Minutes" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setStartDate" prefWidth="75.0" text="Start Date" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setEndDate" prefWidth="67.0" text="End Date" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setStallsTickets" prefWidth="79.0" text="Stalls Prices" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setCirclesTickets" prefWidth="81.0" text="Circles Prices" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="setBalconyPrices" prefWidth="105.0" text="Balcony Prices" />
            </columns>
        </TableView>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="homeAnchorPane" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="50.0">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="homeButton" layoutX="11.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#goHome" text="" />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane fx:id="addShowAnchorPane" layoutY="275.0" prefHeight="125.0" prefWidth="600.0">
            <children>
                <TextField fx:id="showTitle" layoutY="14.0" promptText="Show Title" />
                <TextField fx:id="showMinutes" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="14.0" promptText="Minutes" />
                <TextField fx:id="startDate" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="14.0" promptText="Start Date" />
                <TextField fx:id="endDate" layoutY="50.0" promptText="End Date" />
                <TextField fx:id="setStallsTicketPrices" layoutX="226.0" layoutY="50.0" promptText="Stalls Ticket Prices" />
                <TextField fx:id="setCirclesTicketPrices" layoutX="437.0" layoutY="50.0" promptText="Circles Ticket Prices" />
                <TextField fx:id="setBalconyTicketPrices" layoutY="86.0" promptText="Balcony Ticket Prices" />
                <Button fx:id="saveAndFinishButton" layoutX="485.0" layoutY="86.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addSave" text="Add " />
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="62.0" text="West" />
        <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="79.0" text="End" />
        <Label layoutX="4.0" layoutY="96.0" text="Theatre" />
        <Label layoutY="113.0" text="Management">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Bold" size="8.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <Label layoutX="5.0" layoutY="125.0" text="System" />
    </children>
</Pane>
```

This is my show class

```
package sample;

import API.LocalDateAdapter;
import javafx.beans.property.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@XmlRootElement(name = "show")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"showTitle", "minutes", "startDate", "endDate", "stallsTicketPrices", "circlesTicketPrices", "balconyTicketPrices"})

public class Show {

    private SimpleStringProperty showTitle;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty minutes;
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> startDate;
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> endDate;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty stallsTicketPrices;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty circlesTicketPrices;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty balconyTicketPrices;

    public Show() {

    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setShowTitle (SimpleStringProperty showTitle) {
        this.showTitle = showTitle;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setMinutes (SimpleIntegerProperty minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
    public void setStartDate (ObjectProperty<LocalDate> startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
    public void setEndDate (ObjectProperty<LocalDate> endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setStallsTicketPrices (SimpleDoubleProperty stallsTicketPrices) {
        this.stallsTicketPrices = stallsTicketPrices;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setCirclesTicketPrices (SimpleDoubleProperty circlesTicketPrices) {
        this.circlesTicketPrices = circlesTicketPrices;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setBalconyTicketPrices (SimpleDoubleProperty balconyTicketPrices) {
        this.balconyTicketPrices = balconyTicketPrices;
    }


    /*public Show(){
        this.showTitle = "";
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.startDate = LocalDate.now();
        this.endDate = LocalDate.now();
        this.stallsTicketPrices = 0;
        this.circlesTicketPrices = 0;
        this.balconyTicketPrices = 0;
    }

    public Show(int minutes, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, int stallsTicketPrices, int circlesTicketPrices, int balconyTicketPrices) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.stallsTicketPrices = stallsTicketPrices;
        this.circlesTicketPrices = circlesTicketPrices;
        this.balconyTicketPrices = balconyTicketPrices;
    }*/

    public Show(String showTitle, int minutes, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, double stallsTicketPrices, double circlesTicketPrices, double balconyTicketPrices) {
        this.showTitle =  new SimpleStringProperty(showTitle);
        this.minutes = new SimpleIntegerProperty(minutes);
        this.startDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(startDate);
        this.endDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(endDate);
        this.stallsTicketPrices = new SimpleDoubleProperty(stallsTicketPrices);
        this.circlesTicketPrices = new SimpleDoubleProperty(circlesTicketPrices);
        this.balconyTicketPrices = new SimpleDoubleProperty(balconyTicketPrices);
    }

    public String getShowTitle() {
        return showTitle.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty showTitleProperty() {
        return showTitle;
    }

    public void setShowTitle(String showTitle) {
        this.showTitle.set(showTitle);
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty minutesProperty() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes.set(minutes);
    }

    public LocalDate getStartDate() {
        return startDate.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> startDateProperty() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate.set(startDate);
    }

    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        return endDate.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> endDateProperty() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate.set(endDate);
    }

    public double getStallsTicketPrices() {
        return stallsTicketPrices.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty stallsTicketPricesProperty() {
        return stallsTicketPrices;
    }

    public void setStallsTicketPrices(double stallsTicketPrices) {
        this.stallsTicketPrices.set(stallsTicketPrices);
    }

    public double getCirclesTicketPrices() {
        return circlesTicketPrices.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty circlesTicketPricesProperty() {
        return circlesTicketPrices;
    }

    public void setCirclesTicketPrices(double circlesTicketPrices) {
        this.circlesTicketPrices.set(circlesTicketPrices);
    }

    public double getBalconyTicketPrices() {
        return balconyTicketPrices.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty balconyTicketPricesProperty() {
        return balconyTicketPrices;
    }

    public void setBalconyTicketPrices(double balconyTicketPrices) {
        this.balconyTicketPrices.set(balconyTicketPrices);
    }
}
```

This is my show controller class

```
package Controllers;

import API.Save;
import Lists.ShowList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import sample.Show;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class showController implements Initializable {

    public Pane showPane;
    public TableView<Show> showTableView;
    public TableColumn<Show,String> setShowName;
    public TableColumn<Show,Integer> setShowMinutes;
    public TableColumn<Show,LocalDate> setStartDate;
    public TableColumn<Show,LocalDate> setEndDate;
    public TableColumn<Show,Double> setStallsTickets;
    public TableColumn<Show,Double> setCirclesTickets;
    public TableColumn<Show,Double> setBalconyPrices;
    public AnchorPane homeAnchorPane;
    public Button homeButton;
    public AnchorPane addShowAnchorPane;
    public TextField showTitle;
    public TextField showMinutes;
    public TextField startDate;
    public TextField endDate;
    public TextField setStallsTicketPrices;
    public TextField setCirclesTicketPrices;
    public TextField setBalconyTicketPrices;
    public Button saveAndFinishButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        setShowName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("showTitle"));
        setShowMinutes.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("minutes"));
        setStartDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("startDate"));
        setEndDate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("endDate"));
        setStallsTickets.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("stallsTicketPrices"));
        setCirclesTickets.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("circlesTicketPrices"));
        setBalconyPrices.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("balconyTicketPrices"));
    }

    //final ObservableList<Shows> shows = FXCollections.observableList();

    public void goHome(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../FXML/mainMenu.fxml"));
        showPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
    }

    public void addSave(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException, JAXBException {
        Show show = new Show(showTitle.getText(), Integer.parseInt(showMinutes.getText()), java.time.LocalDate.parse(startDate.getText()), java.time.LocalDate.parse(endDate.getText()), Double.parseDouble(setStallsTicketPrices.getText()), Double.parseDouble(setCirclesTicketPrices.getText()), Double.parseDouble(setBalconyTicketPrices.getText()));
        showTableView.getItems().add(show);
        clearText(actionEvent);
    }

    public void clearText (ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        showTitle.setText("");
        showMinutes.setText("");
        startDate.setText("");
        endDate.setText("");
        setStallsTicketPrices.setText("");
        setCirclesTicketPrices.setText("");
        setBalconyTicketPrices.setText("");
    }
}
```

I have used resources for the JAXB from :

- https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/write-object-to-xml/
- https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/
- https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/

EDIT : I am after changing the showList from the examples I was given but now I have a collection that I need to implement by myself now.

```
package Lists;

import java.util.*;

class ShowIterator<Show> implements Iterator<Show> {
    private ShowNode<Show> pos; //Current position
    public ShowIterator(ShowNode<Show> fnode) { pos=fnode; }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return pos!=null;
    }

    @Override
    public Show next() {
        ShowNode<Show> temp=pos;
        pos=pos.next;
        return temp.getShows();
    }
}

//ShowNode unchanged but removed as inner class from ShowList
class ShowNode<Show> {
    public ShowNode<Show> next=null;
    private Show shows; //ADT reference!
    public Show getShows() { return shows; }
    public void setShows(Show s) { shows=s; }
}

public class ShowList<Show> implements List<Show> {
    public ShowNode<Show> head=null;
    public boolean add(Show show) { //Add element to head of list
        ShowNode<Show> fn=new ShowNode<>();
        fn.setShows(show);
        fn.next=head;
        head=fn;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Show> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends Show> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {

    }

    @Override
    public Show get(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Show set(int index, Show element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, Show element) {

    }

    @Override
    public Show remove(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Show> listIterator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<Show> listIterator(int index) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Show> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Show> iterator() {
        return new ShowIterator<Show>(head);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is my code for another list but this time for the performance list but it uses an array instead of a linked list.

```
package Lists;

public class PerformanceList<Performance> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Performance[] data=(Performance[]) new Object [10]; //init capacity of 10
    private int index=0;

    public void add(Performance performance) {
        if(index>=data.length) { //Array is full!
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Performance[] temp=(Performance[]) new Object [(int)(data.length*1.5+1)];
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                temp[i]=data[i];
            data=temp;
        }

        data[index]=performance;
        index++;
    }

    public Performance get(int i) {
        return data[i];
    }

    public void delete(int i) {
        for(int x=i;x<data.length-1;x++)
            data[x]=data[x+1];
        index--;
    }

    public int size() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

I will need to do this for 2 other classes but once I get this working then I'll be good to go. Any help would be beneficial

With thanks.

Comment: I understand if I have a couple of code commented out or it can be done better but I'll polish everything out once I'll have everything else working.

Comment: Please try to focus the question. It looks a bit broad to me. It is important to ask questions with clear concise problem statements. 
If the main issue is the implementing a linked list, please show your implementation ([mre]) and explain what is not working as expected.

Comment: @c0der , well I'm having several problems but most importantly is the implementation of the list , apologies for any inconveniences. I have my linked list currently taken from here : https://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/ . Although I tried using different guides but I just don't understand the implementation of it into the table view show controller as in I want to add a new show but also save it at the same time if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm aware that I need an observable list in my controller so it'll be something like `final ObservableList<Shows> shows = FXCollections.observableList(showlist);`

Comment: [edit] your question to reflect your question. "please show your implementation (minimal reproducible example) and explain what is not working as expected."

Comment: There are a lot of methods you need to implement for `List` that you'll never call in your own code, so why do more work than required. You've got an iterator which should allow you to iterate through the list adding the elements to the `TableView.items` list one by one.

Comment: Also JAXB seems like a more advanced topic than actually required of you. Sure it's a nice API, but if you're even barred from using common collection classes, using that API is just taking a slegehammer to crack a nut. Why not use something like [StaX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/example.html#bnbgx) in the end I'm pretty sure this'll result in less work for you... The question is too unfocused to be on topic here though...

Answer (score 0):

I got it all working maybe it's not the best way but I've used xStream for the save as I had it from last year and it works. I changed the SimpleStringProperty to just String and for the list I've used [this list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66685/self-made-linked-list) .

```
//Saves the shows list to a .XML file
    public void save() throws IOException {
        //XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        ObjectOutputStream out = xstream.createObjectOutputStream(new FileWriter("shows.xml"));
        out.writeObject(showsList);
        out.close();
    }
```

Sorry if this is still unfocused but it's my first time asking on stackOverflow. 
With thanks.